# how can I get it so when I press a button on my main.storybaord it moves to a specific game scene file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

I already have some code but it doesn't seem to work well with what I'm trying to do with my multiple storyboard screens, is there any other way to do that would fit my needs

[my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdn33.jpg)

**note:** im kind of new to coding so a simple solution would be much appreciated ; also the storyboards that have a black background are the ones I want to use for my interface ; also all my games scenes are in folders on the left

Comment: What is the reason of doing this? Why not having one SKView, one GameViewController and multiple SKScenes?

Comment: the multi SKScenes are for the multiple game modes and the rest is for organization